# mount bind inside container is not reflecting outside container

Tags: mount, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to bind host dir to some dir inside container and expecting changes done inside container should reflect on host.

Here is the steps I have followed

created /hostdir on host and run ubuntu container in privileged mode

```
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# mkdir /hostdir
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker run -itd --privileged --name ubuntu -v /hostdir:/hostdir:z ubuntu
76aebded33274e95a6f569d0831aee4df27e9f200a8fd0401448239bd6f5bf80
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker exec -it ubuntu bash
```

creating a container_dir inside container

```
root@76aebded3327:/# mkdir /container_dir
```

binding the two directory (successfull)

```
root@76aebded3327:/# mount --bind /container_dir /hostdir
```

creating a file named hello.txt inside /container_dir

```
root@76aebded3327:/# cd container_dir/
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# touch hello.txt
```

its get reflected inside /hostdir as it is bind mount to /container_dir

```
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# ls /hostdir/
hello.txt
```

exit container and check on host , is the same reflected

```
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# exit

[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# ls /hostdir/
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# ls /hostdir/ | wc -l
0
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]#
```

the content are not getting reflected.
I am missing something or doing completely wrong, please help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design – mounts done inside a container are not visible outside, for several reasons.

The container runs in a separate mount namespace (not just a simple chroot), and Docker most likely configures the new namespace in "private" mode, partly to prevent the container's various mounts from cluttering the host's `findmnt`, and partly to make it easier to disassemble all mounts when the container exits.

(When all mounts are only visible from inside the namespace, it's enough to kill all processes – then the mounts will be torn down automatically by the kernel. But if some of them are visible externally, then a 'host OS' process could potentially hold them "in use".)

You might need something like `mount --make-[r]shared /` at the correct time to make internal mounts visible externally. I don't have a more precise answer right now.

You can use the `unshare` and `nsenter` tools to experiment with namespaces without involving Docker – e.g. run `unshare --mount --propagation=private` in one terminal, mount something, then run `findmnt` to see it reporting different results "inside" and "outside" the 'unshare' process.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was making the Docker bind mount `shared` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821915) to a similar question "How to expose a container's mount point to the host?":

`-v /hostdir:/hostdir:shared`

According to [Docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#short-syntax-5) the `z` option should achieve something similar, assuming your host OS uses SELinux, but I didn't try it.